# Linking Activex Textboxes in Excel so text flows between textbox1 to textbox2

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty sure this is simply not possible. However, would it be possible to have one large vertical textbox and create a blank area in the middle? That is one worsheet with two forms (vertically aligned), with a single large textbox running down the right side of the forms. At, say, line 50 text is taken to line 70... (the "2nd" textbox.)

So the textbox would give every appearance of allowing overflow of text from textbox1 to another textbox (actually still textbox1)

Comment: Why you need that?

Comment: I'm trying to recreate this and I am having a tough time understanding what OP wants.

Comment: It's for a printable form that has page 1 and sometimes Page 2 (where there is a lot of text required.) The form is in wide (landscape) format. Also, the text is mostly copy/pasted. At present, I block select the overflow, select cut. Then paste the overflow into textbox2. A single paste action would be better though.

Comment: The blank area in the middle, is the non-printing area between the two forms. That is, on the Excel worksheet, there are two set print areas.

Comment: can you post a picture of the desired result?

Comment: The picture shows base of form 1 (page1) and top of form 2 (page 2). The single textbox would run from top of form 1 to base of form 2. The area where blank lines need to be generated would be the middle (non-printable) area. https://ibb.co/x763Vpj

Comment: `Linking Activex Textboxes in Excel so text flows between textbox1 to textbox2. I'm pretty sure this is simply not possible.` It is possible. However in your case use three textboxes. One below the other without borders so that they appear as one [SAMPLE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qxcpx6rr6916g1/3TBSample.png?dl=0). Center TB will not have anything. Set the length of the 1st TB to whatever you want. When the text is full in that TB, transfer the text into the 3rd TB. Can be handled in TB Change event.

Comment: BTW you may also know that it is possible. I will give you an example to refresh your memory ;) and then perhaps you may agree with me. You may have entered one big serial number in many software Installations? There are many textboxes separated by a "-" and when you paste the  serial number in the first box, it gets distributed in the rest of the boxes? It works on the same principle.

Comment: I only assumed it was not possible, because every google result only gives me using textbox2 = textbox1...but that, of course, duplicates...whereas what I need  is automatic overflow from box 1 to box 2 (eg box1: the quick brown fox   box2: jumps over.... Anyways, the extra box in the middle is so - doh! obvious. That's for that.

Comment: Actually, my thought was to use one long text box and then another text box (or even a rectangular shape) in the middle. However, it seems Excel doesn't have the option to set the middle object with the property of forcing text to flow around (but not through.) I don't really understand your three textbox option, unless you're refering to manually cut (or copy) the overflowed text, and paste into textbox3.

Comment: `unless you're refering to manually cut (or copy) the overflowed text, and paste into textbox3` Abosolutely not. It can be achieved using code. You will have to take care of two things. **1.** When the user is typing and the max length is reached, shift the focus from TB1 to TB2. **2.** You need to trap the Paste event and then segregate the text into respective TBs.

Comment: I understand now. Actually it's a pity that line count rather than character count is available, because WWWW is very different to ;;;;. Thanks, I'll look into using character count (I'll just play it conservative, to avoid the issue of overshooting Box1.